# pyvlfeat error during installation: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python-mt-py26

Tags: installation

I've haven't been successful in finding a solution to the following error which I get during the pyvlfeat 0.1.1a3 installation: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python-mt-py26

I've installed boost python. Here's the console output:

```
lenovo@lenovo-ThinkPad-T61:~/Downloads/pyvlfeat-0.1.1a3$ ipython
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:03:08) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.12 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: run setup.py clean
running clean
removing 'build/temp.linux-i686-2.7' (and everything under it)

In [2]: run setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_vlfeat' extension
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/mser
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/sift
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/imop
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/misc
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/kmeans
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/quickshift
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/aib.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/aib.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/generic.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/generic.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/hikmeans.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/hikmeans.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/ikmeans.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/ikmeans.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/imopv.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/imopv.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/mathop.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/mathop.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/mathop_sse2.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/mathop_sse2.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/pgm.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/pgm.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/rodrigues.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/rodrigues.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/stringop.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/stringop.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/getopt_long.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/getopt_long.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/host.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/host.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/imopv_sse2.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/imopv_sse2.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/mser.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/mser.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/random.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/random.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/sift.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/sift.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/dsift.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/dsift.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/vl/quickshift.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/quickshift.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/mser/vl_erfill.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/mser/vl_erfill.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/mser/vl_mser.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/mser/vl_mser.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/sift/vl_sift.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/sift/vl_sift.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/sift/vl_dsift.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/sift/vl_dsift.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/sift/vl_siftdescriptor.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/sift/vl_siftdescriptor.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/imop/vl_imsmooth.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/imop/vl_imsmooth.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/misc/vl_binsum.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/misc/vl_binsum.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/kmeans/vl_hikmeans.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/kmeans/vl_hikmeans.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/kmeans/vl_ikmeans.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/kmeans/vl_ikmeans.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/kmeans/vl_hikmeanspush.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/kmeans/vl_hikmeanspush.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/kmeans/vl_ikmeanspush.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/kmeans/vl_ikmeanspush.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/quickshift/vl_quickshift.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/quickshift/vl_quickshift.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ivlfeat/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c vlfeat/py_vlfeat.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/py_vlfeat.o -msse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/aib.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/generic.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/hikmeans.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/ikmeans.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/imopv.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/mathop.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/mathop_sse2.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/pgm.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/rodrigues.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/stringop.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/getopt_long.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/host.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/imopv_sse2.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/mser.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/random.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/sift.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/dsift.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/vl/quickshift.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/mser/vl_erfill.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/mser/vl_mser.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/sift/vl_sift.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/sift/vl_dsift.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/sift/vl_siftdescriptor.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/imop/vl_imsmooth.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/misc/vl_binsum.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/kmeans/vl_hikmeans.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/kmeans/vl_ikmeans.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/kmeans/vl_hikmeanspush.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/kmeans/vl_ikmeanspush.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/quickshift/vl_quickshift.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/vlfeat/py_vlfeat.o -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/_vlfeat.so -msse -shared -lboost_python-mt-py26
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python-mt-py26
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1


In [3]:
```

Comment: I'm the pyvlfeat maintainer. I haven't had time/interest to look at it for almost a year, but I'm pretty interested in experimenting with it again. I'd like to drop the boost.python and matplotlib dependencies completely. Perhaps make matplotlib optional. As of 10/1/2012 VLFeat got "PASCAL2" funding so I'm waiting to see where that leads before spending time rewriting the bindings. As for the error, have you checked for libboost_python-mt-py26.{a,so} in your library search path? If it's someplace else you need to change your library search path, if not, you should reinstall boost.python.

Answer (score 6):

A quick fix to this is to simply edit the setup.py for pyvlfeat and modify the LinkArgs line to refer to your installation of boost-python.  For my system, (and likely many others) this amounts to just changing -lboost_python-mt-py26 to -lboost_python-mt-py27 to refer to the proper Python revision.