# Using my Installation of Boost Python for PyVlFeat

Tags: python, boost

I am trying to install PyVlFeat and the installation is failing with exactly this issue mentioned here. 
[pyvlfeat error during installation: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python-mt-py26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071471/pyvlfeat-error-during-installation-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lboost-python-mt-p)

As per the answer mentioned there, I need to change the reference of "-lboost_python-mt-py26" to the correct version of Boost Python I have on my system.
I am on ubuntu 14.04 and I tried to detect the version of my boost python by using this command "ls /usr/lib/libboost_python*"

I don't seem to have any libraries with a similar name there. However, I have installed Boost Python using this command "sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev" as mentioned here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891667/boost-undefined-reference-ubuntu-14-04-boost-1-54

Since Boost Python is already there, how should I use it correctly to compile PyVlFeat.

Comment: I have posted this in askubuntu and got the answer.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/546323/cannot-find-lboost-python-mt-error-when-using-boost/546823#546823

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -mt suffix had been removed from Boost Libraries. The installed Boost libraries are multi-threading safe.

Changing the reference to "-lboost_python-py27" (Removing -mt suffix and using proper version of python will solve the problem.