# How to install Boost.Python on Windows 7 in order to install a python package?

Tags: python, python-2.7, boost, boost-python

I want to install the [pyvlfeat](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvlfeat/) package. It requires **Boost.Python**.

When I run the command

```
 python.exe setup.py build
```

I receive the following message:

> C:\Users\alex\Anaconda\Scripts\gcc.bat -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Users\A
>   lexkow\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ivlfeat
>       / -IC:\Users\alex\Anaconda\include -IC:\Users\alex\Anaconda\PC -c vlfeat/m
>       ser/vl_erfill.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\vlfeat\mser\vl_erfill.o -m
>       sse2 -O2 -fPIC -w
>       In file included from vlfeat/mser/vl_erfill.cpp:7:0:
>       vlfeat/mser/../py_vlfeat.h:18:28: **fatal error: boost/python.hpp: No such file or
>        directory**

Which tells me **Boost.Python is not installed correctly** on my computer, or that I don't launch the python install command correctly.

The package INSTALL instructions are :

> Building the Module on a Unix System --
>       The C++ wrappers require Boost.Python to be installed:
>
> $ sudo apt-get install boost-python1.35-dev
>
> pyvlfeat uses distutils, so to build the library:
>
> $ python setup.py build

As I am on Windows I can't sudo apt-get, so  I downloaded **[boost 1.57.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/)**  and extracted it into

> C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_57_0

It did not change the result. And now I don't know what I should do:

When I read the  [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/building.html)

- The section 3: "No-Install Quick Start" explains how to build an extension module called extending and test it by running a Python script called test_extending.py.  I don't think that is what I want to achieve and **it seems outdated** because it talks about the bjam build driver.
- The section 4: "Installing Boost.Python on your system" looks more interresting, but it says the information is in the Getting Started Guide, and it is not.

**How to install Boost.Python on Windows 7 in order to install a python package ? ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am looking at the [setup.py](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~asdfghjkl-deactivatedaccount1/pyvlfeat/trunk/view/head:/setup.py) file. It looks like you can set `BOOST_PATH` at the top. You should set that to the correct path to the Boost you downloaded, I think.

Comment: Thanks. It look like they changed the setup.py file on the trunk. Because it is different than the one I downloaded from the package .tar.gz  I will check if it works.

Comment: I don't have the error now but I have the same error as this person:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071471/pyvlfeat-error-during-installation-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lboost-python-mt-p Changing to  -lboost_python-mt-py27 does not correct the problem.

Comment: Yeah but they say to puth the containing folder of a file called *libboost_python-mt* and I don't have such a file. I tried building boost like explained here http://www.mantidproject.org/Building_Boost_Python and renaming the files but with no success.